# Changing the framesize of uiview with animation not changing the framesize of subviews automatically

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, subviews

i am working to animate a uiview(parent view named 'popupVw') which contains 11 subviews (7 buttons,2 labels,2 imageview). Initially the the frame size is :

```
CGRect Frame = CGRectMake(10, 10 ,320, 0);
```

& new frame size is:

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10 ,320, 300);



[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{popupVw.frame = newFrame;}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // do stuff here after animation finished
                 }];
```

So basically i am changing the height of view from 0 to 300 . & then from 300 to 0 again. to achieve show hide animation.

Consider it as a popup in the middle of the screen appearing from 0 to 300 height . This popup contains subviews & a close button at the top right corner. By clicking this close button the popup again decreases to height from 300 to 0. parent popup view is animating correctly. But the subviews are visible before the height increases to maximum. & visible till the height of parent view goes to 0 again. So basically only the parent view is animating & not the inner view.

The animation is working properly on parent view but the subviews are not animating with the parent view. As a result when i change the height of uiview from 300 to 0 then all the subviews still visible & only the parent uiview's height become 0.

Do i need to put animation for them seperately? if yes then how can i do this for the height change ? Or is there any other approach which i can use to achieve the same result?

i tried autoresizing mask . but its not working for me :

```
pointerImgVw.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin  ;
```

Below are the srceengrabs of the problem :

[image]
[image]
[image]

The cross button at the top right corner is subview of the animating popup. What i want is the cross button should not be outside of the animating view. For example in the 2nd screenshot only the half cross button should be visible.outside part should not be visible

Comment: Try UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight instead.

Comment: @verbumdei i tried using UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight but it just increases the height of the subview with the size of parent view. I mean . if parentView's height increasing from 0 to 300 then the height of subview is also increasing.

Comment: How do you want the subviews to animate? Or just set clipToBounds?

Comment: I have edited the question. What i want is subviews should be hiding/visible with the parent view.They always should remain inside of main view

Comment: How about just animating the alpha of the view instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the **clipsToBounds** property of the parent view to **YES**

i.e     parentView.clipsToBounds=YES

Answer (score 2):

Try using `options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews`.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                     animations:^{
                         // animate here...
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

EDIT:
OK, got it. Then you need to have another view (lets call it coverView) inside of your animating view. The coverView will be the same size as the animating view and will be on top of all other subviews, so it hides them. Now when you animate the view open, you should animate the coverView to disappear and vice versa.

Comment: No i can't do that because my main parent frame lies in the middle of the screen & started to display from the middle of the screen. There is no other view behind which i can hide this animating view. you are suggesting the slidein/slideout animation in which the height of the frame remains fixed

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot of how the view looks opened and closed? It will be easier for us to help you find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Eli Ganem , Screen shots are added.

Comment: No this is not what i asked.Please look at the 2nd screenshot where the cross button is half out of the animating frame. At this position it half cross button(which is outside the animating parent view) should not be visible. Same effect as if the subviews were part of the animating view itself & not subview.